# BeautifulSoup with dynamic href

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, href

Trying python 3.4 beautifulsoup to grab a zip file from a webpage so I can unzip and download it into a folder. I can get the beautifulsoup to print() all the hrefs on the page but I want a specific href **ending** in, "=Hospital_Revised_Flatfiles.zip". Is that possible? This is what I have so far, only the list of href from the url.

the full href of the file is, https://data.medicare.gov/views/bg9k-emty/files/Dlx5-ywq01dGnGrU09o_Cole23nv5qWeoYaL-OzSLSU?content_type=application%2Fzip%3B%20charset%3Dbinary&filename=Hospital_Revised_Flatfiles.zip
, but the crazy stuff in the middle changes when they update the file and there is no way of knowing what it changes to.

Please let me know if there is something I left out of the question that might be helpful. I'm using Python 3.4 and BeautifulSoup4 (bs4)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import re

url = "https://data.medicare.gov/data/hospital-compare"

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import re

url = "https://data.medicare.gov/data/hospital-compare"

r = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
   if link.has_key('href'):
      if(link['href'].endswith("=Hospital_Revised_Flatfiles.zip")):
         print(link['href'])
```

Comment: When I use that code I get an "Invalid Syntax" error

Comment: Try this i have modified and checked the code and it is working now.

Comment: I think this is close to what I need. The only problem is it doesn't give the whole link, just the href that ends in "hospital_revised_flatfiles.zip". Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I changed just two things in the code to make it work. 1) changed has_key to has_attr 2) print('https://data.medicare.gov'+link['href']. Thanks @WhoAmI for the assistance